# RecyclerView NativeExpressAdView issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adview

I am using a NativeExpressAdview inside my RecyclerView. As I scroll down and again scroll up just as the Ad becomes visible again I am seeing a duplicate of the Ad becoming visible under the Navigation bar.

These are recycler view callbacks from log. The second image gets visible around onBind

```
10-05 13:52:29.368 13410-13410/com.test.experiment D/WSS: onRecycle AD
10-05 13:52:29.368 13410-13410/com.test.experiment D/WSS: onBind AD
10-05 13:52:31.863 13410-13410/com.test.experiment D/WSS: onRecycle AD
10-05 13:52:32.380 13410-13410/com.test.experiment D/WSS: onBind AD
```

What could be the problem ?

[image]

**Edit**:

I have checked the sample app at [sample](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/tree/master/advanced/NativeExpressRecyclerViewExample) and it is exhibiting the same behaviour.

Comment: Does it happen on a specific device or all devices?

Comment: I tested on a N5 and Android one both stock.

Comment: @LakshmanChilukuri Have you found the solution for this?

Comment: Yes. The problem stopped after some support library updates.